# Dynamic dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown using jquery

```
   var rooms = $("<select />");

   $(res.data).each(function () {
         var option = $("<option />");
         option.html(this.name);
         option.val(this.id);
         rooms.append(option);
   });
```

dropdown is created when i directly append it to `append_parent_div`

```
$('#append_parent_div').append(rooms);
```

but when i append it with several div's

```
  $('#append_parent_div').append('<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12"> <div class="form-group">'+rooms+'</div></div>');
```

then  `[object Object]` is getting appended in my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use `+`, but `,`:

example:

`$('#append_parent_div').append('<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12"> <div class="form-group">', rooms, '</div></div>');`

Like documentantion said: https://api.jquery.com/append/

You were concatenating strings with an object

Working example:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="append_parent_div">
    </div>
    <script>
    var rooms = $("<select />");
    var res =  {};
    res.data = [{name:"name number 1", id:1},{name:"name number 2", id:2}]

    $(res.data).each(function () {
            var option = $("<option />");
            option.html(this.name);
            option.val(this.id);
            rooms.append(option);
    });

  $('#append_parent_div').append('<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12"> <div class="form-group">', rooms, '</div></div>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is one issue dropdown is created outside the form group i want to create it within form group

Comment: oh sorry, didnt understood that... so you can use 

`$('#append_parent_div').append('<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12"><div class="form-group">' + rooms.get(0).outerHTML + '</div></div>');`